# How to output values in array?

Tags: php, html, arrays

Hello I have the following variable in my PHP:

```
$art= [ 
        'places' => ['America','Paris','Italy','Japan'],
        'photographer' => ['Samantha','Hannah','David','Albert'],
    ];
```

I am just trying to output 'places' only into my HTML code. Keep getting "Illegal String Offset" warning.

Why is my following code not working?

```
<?php foreach($art as $value): ?> 
      <?= $value['places'] ?>
    <?php endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php foreach ($art["places"] as $value): ?>
<?= $value ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

you should loop the $art["places"];